# Can I run a 6V lamp on 12V without damage?

Tags: power-supply, led, 12v

I am modifying LED headlamps and the LED chips inside says 6V and 2W. However. It came with a pack of two 18650 batteries so it gets 8.4V max when they're full and 7.2 when those are going empty. So it already runs on more than 6V and it's fine?

Can I hook these lights up to 12V without damage. If I read this right they should take no more than 0.5 amps on the 12V and then it's the correct 6W.

Can someone confirm this, will it work?

Comment: No, 12V is too high. Just because something is already high doesn't mean it's okay to go even higher. Bad logic.  Wattage does matter but the distribution of that wattage between volts and amps also matters. Like torque and RPM. Just because you need 700HP to tow a trailer at some speed doesn't mean that the torque and speed don't matter. You need enough torque to move the trailer and enough RPM to go at the desired speed. Required torque and RPM or volts and amps determine wattage, not the other way around. So it will pull 0.5A *if* you convert that 12V to volts/amps the lamp can use.

Comment: (That is, 0.5A will be pulled from the 12V supply and be converted into the volts/amps the lamp needs)

Comment: *It depends*. If the lamp only contains a resistive dropper, you can make it work by adding an appropriate external resistor. We can tell you how to adapt the lamp to work on 12V if you show us pictures of the lamp's internals and/or a reverse-engineered schematic of it. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: How do you know it is directly connected to battery? Maybe there is a regulator chip between LED and batteries?

Comment: There's a lot of ways that it could have 6V applied to the LED chips with 8.4V outside -- post pictures, or trace out a schematic and post that.

Comment: There is no way it puts the output of two 18650 batteries directly across the diode. That would result in tens to hundreds of watts of dissipation in a 2W rated chip. The chip would burn up instantly.

Answer (score 4):

STOP! DO NOT DO THIS!

You are playing with forces you do not understand. I say this out of kindness and concern for saftey. You are asking this kind of question on this forum suggests you need to learn things before you start playing with real world applications.

Now to answer you question: putting 12V across a 6V device will most probably kill the device. However, as we do not know anything about this 6V device, we cannot be sure what will happen.

The question is what does happens inside the black box. As the lights have been supplied with (what I assume are) two series connecting li-ion cells, making between 6V and 8.2V (depending on precisesly which li-ion cell and charge level). We can assume that the light has been designed to work with a voltage input in this range.

This is still significantly less than the 12V you're asking about.

If we knew what was happening inside the box, it may well be OK with 12V. However I would not risk it.

If you have multiple of these lamps and a good variable voltage power supply, you could connect one up and slowly increase votlage in to see what happens. At some point something will blow, the question is what and how soon. Parts may be able to handel 12V fine for a few seconds before they get damaged. Or they may even last half an hour without any apparent issue, but then fail after 20 hours of use. Which could be particularly dangerous with a head light which you seem to be talking about here.

On the assumption that you only have one of these lamps, and you need to get something functional out of this, my adivce is: read and learn about how electronics work. Then, and only when you understand things, you could put a DCDC buck converter in to take the votlage down from 12V to 7V or so. I say 7V, on the assumption that the input is 2 series li-ion cells, which you can show oppearting at 7V.

Comment: Just to support this post - working OK at a nominal 12v on a bench power supply does not therfore mean it's a good idea to fit to a vehicle with a "12v" system, as these run at about 14.4v when running/charging and can spike as high as 36v during events such as the starter motor disengaging. I had a module that was rated for 16v run perfectly fine for a week in a car, then one day it literally started smoking and died, and not even during a high-stress event. Littelfuse have a good appnote on "automotive transients" for those unfamiliar with how nasty cars are to electronics.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a LED driver chip and it works on 8.4V then it must be rated for a maximum voltage higher than 8.4V. Maybe it's 9V, maybe it's 36V, who knows. You could look at the references of the chips and try to find their datasheets online, but if they're tiny chips with 2-3 letter codes, good luck with that.

If the chip is rated for more than 12V, and all the other components are also rated for this, which is impossible to know since ceramic capacitors have no labels... then it should work on 12V.

Otherwise, it'll probably work for a while, and fail unexpectedly when you need it most, for example when going downhill very fast on a bicycle at night.